# Stack jquery in expressJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm looking for a way to stack jquery from the express app.js file.
Maybe this is not possible but I need to use jquery in the `app.js` which modifies the html file.

Example:

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const $ = global.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  $("#click").click(function(e){
        console.log('click');   
    }) 
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Express - Jquery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <button id="click" type="button">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong method...
If someone has already done this

Comment: This is not possible. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @goto1 It's a bit long to explain, basically, I would like to use the twitter API (from app.js) and inject the results into the html file using jquery

Comment: Then I suggest creating a separate route in your `app.js` that calls the Twitter API and returns the data as JSON. Then in your `index.html` you can use `jQuery` to make an `AJAX` request to grab that data. Another option would be to use a template engine, such as `ejs` and then use the `res.render` method to pass data you need/get from the Twitter API.

Comment: Effectively! It may be a solution ... I will inquire about this rating there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code belongs *client side*, not *server side*:

```
$("#click").click(function(e){
    console.log('click');   
})
```

You'd put it in your `index.html`.  (Or in an external script referenced by your `index.html`.)  For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Express - Jquery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <button id="click" type="button">Click</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#click").click(function(e){
        console.log('click');
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The server-side code has no concept of the in-browser DOM.  It's just returning the page to the client as a response to the HTTP request it received.  The client-side JavaScript on that page is what interacts with the DOM in the browser.

Comment: That's what I thought! I use the API in the app.js, obviously, I cannot use my API keys in the html file.
Pity! I will try with another framework

Comment: @Julien: You might be looking for some kind of node/express template engine to bind data values to a page template.  Another option could be to separate this action entirely.  Your client-side page could make a separate AJAX request to another server-side route which queries the external API and returns just the data as JSON.  Then the client-side code can use jQuery to populate the page with that data, if you're set on using jQuery.

Comment: Effectively! I think that's what I'm going to have to do.
To go further in the explanation, I created a desktop app with electron which analyzes the stream of tweeter and brings the result to Vis.js Network
The concern is that I cannot distribute software with my API keys inside, that is why I want to try to adapt it with express.
I think you put me on the right track!